# VBA code Fill down visible column after filter another column

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with my code. I am new to VBA so not quite understand to do this right. Already search answer from another thread but it too advance I cannot follow it.

Here the situation I want.
at column S I use vlookup to find match data from sheet3 and filter with N/A value. then I want to fill down visible data in column Q with "Fulfilled" but I what get is it fill my Q2 with header value and do not fill to last row.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("S2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

' vlookup from sheet3

Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-14],Sheet3!C[-16],1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("S2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("S2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$20000").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="#N/A"

' here it don't fill to last row 

Range("Q2").Select
ActiveCell.FillDown
```

Many thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofill needs to know the range to autofill, not only the top cell. Supposing the only problem you have is in the last part, try this instead:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Columns("B"). _
       SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FillDown
End With
```

Or it could be `.value = "Fulfilled"` instead of `.Filldown`, depending on what you want to do.

That said, think of refactoring your code to get rid of the `Select`, `ActiveSheet` and `Copy/Paste` stuff` and work with qualified ranges.